# Que significa el argumento -D al hacer un npm install

Tags: npm

Hola a todos estoy empezando a hacer proyectos donde necesito de módulos que instalo mediante `npm install` preguntaba que significa el argumento -D al hacer `npm install -D <modulo>`
Me está costando buscar información acerca de esto por eso pregunto. De paso no sé si sería mucho pedir que me dijerais algún listado con los argumentos más frecuentes y una descripción, algún enlace o algo... Por ejemplo -u --save -f etc.

Un saludo.

Comment: Pues llevo literal un par de días empezando con node, y ni sabía a ciencia cierta lo que era siquiera npm, un tanto borde el comentario pero bueno, agradezco el enlace. -D = --save-dev Todo aclarado.